# How to profile a Java thread status summary from a script

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, profiling

I am aware that tools like [jvisualvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) and [JConsole](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) are good visual tools to monitor the status of a java process threads.
What I want is a command line tool that invokes a java process (or attaches to one) and for a given thread (by name), prints the summary of this thread status when the process exits.
For example:

```
$ sometool $pid
$ sometool java -jar myapp.jar -a 1 -b 2 ...
20% runnable
50% waiting
30% blocked
```

I need this because I am running experiments that invoke my java process tens of times with different parameters and i want to graph the waiting/total time for the various runs. The jvisualvm is of no use, unless it can be invoked in a command line mode with no UI at all. This may be possible by the above tools, but I am not an expert in Java profiling.

Update: Found [MXBeans](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html), but I have to write some code to retrieve the numbers. I will give it a try, but a ready solution would be nice.

Comment: Have you checked http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html?

Comment: Yes I did, but this is a one-time stack trace, should i call it periodically and do the math at the end? I am looking for a straightforward way, because jvisualvm already displays such information in a pie chart.

Comment: side question: does waiting time really matter? shouldn't you be measuring application level throughput and/or latency?

Comment: Yes it matters, we are doing distributed experiments that measure the speedup over non-distributed, taking into consideration wait time due to synchronization between different process on remote machines.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing my own profiler using [ThreadMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html) right inside the class.
I enabled CPU monitoring in the beginning and logged the time breakdown periodically and at the end, check these 2 functions:

```
protected static void initMXBean()
{
    mxBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
    mxBean.setThreadContentionMonitoringEnabled(true);
    mxBean.setThreadCpuTimeEnabled(true);
}

protected static void logMXBean()
{
    long[] threadIds = mxBean.getAllThreadIds();
    ThreadInfo[] threadInfos =
                    mxBean.getThreadInfo(threadIds);

    for (ThreadInfo threadInfo : threadInfos) {
      System.out.println(
          threadInfo.getThreadName() +
          " blocked " + threadInfo.getBlockedTime()/1e6 +
          " waited " + threadInfo.getWaitedTime()/1e6 +
          " cpu " + mxBean.getThreadCpuTime(threadInfo.getThreadId())/1e9
      );
    }

}
```